# Is remote sensing somehow related to signal processing?

Tags: discussion, support

I wonder if remote sensing is related to signal processing and if I can have an advertisement like the following here in this meta site?

[Are there remote sensing experts who attend this community?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/are-there-remote-sensing-experts-who-attend-this-community)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there remote sensing experts who attend this community?](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/are-there-remote-sensing-experts-who-attend-this-community)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are one or two!  I'm one.  I'm not sure how to add an advertisement here, though?

Comment: In beta sites you cannot create an ad. Because they don't have a thread named community promotion ads in their meta like [other sites](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/community-promotion-ads-2015) but you can create your own thread to inform others. Like the one I've added in Earth Science. They taught me how to do so.